# Can Vista Windows Explorer be repaired/fixed?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I'm running Windows Vista Home Premium on a Sony Vaio laptop.  I think somehow my Windows Explorer has become corrupted.  I don't recall any certain inciting incident like installing an unreputable 3rd party app or hardware failure but just recently my system won't wake after it's been left idle longer that 20 minutes and goes to sleep.  I've also had problems launch certain apps, like Adobe InDesign CS3, that just basically freeze the system but leave mouse movements functioning for a short time before freezing the entire system which requires a hard reboot to  resolve the freeze.  The system seems to run normally when used but I fear there's a looming possibility that this is a house of cards and will all come crashing down soon.

My question is this, can Windows Explorer be repaired/fixed?  Before reformatting the system and starting over, which is most likely what I'm going to be forced to do, I'd like explore (no pun intended) my options in fixing the problem with a patch or reinstall or something of that nature.  Reformatting my system will eat up a day or two of my time and I just don't have the time to spare right now.

Comment: Vista Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a automated repair if you have a CD of windows vista. Boot on the CD and instead of choosing install, choose automated repair and this will replace any corrupted files that might be in the Explorer program.

If you don't have the CD of windows vista, you can burn one by following [theses instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-make-a-windows-vista-repair-disk-if-you-dont-have-one/)

Comment: I would also try running the System File checker. Open an elevated command prompt and enter: sfc /scannow

Answer (score 0):

Try making another user account.  Explorer may work fine in a new account, which will save you the bother of having to reinstall the OS and all your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be an explorer issue, run chkdsk /r, then run a memory and hard disk diagnostic
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/m-p/301638#M3294

You can also run a SFC
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936212

.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming it's Explorer based on nothing at all.  Run the Task Manager and see if a process is getting stuck.  Also check the System Logs.